# Display content dynamically based on user input using php and jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a form that will display a list of transactions based on the name and date.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>options/history">
  Name
  <input name="name" type="text" id="name" />
  date
  <input name="date" type="text" id="date" />
  <input name="find" type="submit" id="find" value="find" />
</form>
```

Once the form is submitted all the relevant details are being displayed.

Can someone explain to me how I can use jquery to loads the data on the same page?

I'm new to jquery and learning stuff. I did some research and below is what I have found:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#find').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>options/history",
                    success: function(data) {
                       alert('Data Loaded');
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

And also how do I pass the form variables to my controller? Is it possible to directly pass the values to the controller or do I have to pass it along with the URL?

Comment: What exactly did you find?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form1').submit(function() {
            // get the data of the form
            var data_form = $('#form1').serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                data: data_form,
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>options/history",
                success: function(data) {
                   alert('Data Loaded');
                   // Your data is in the var data returned, you can use it with, for example: $("#content").html(data);

                }
            });
            // Prevent default behaviour
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused here. But I suppose you actually want this:

```
$('form#form1').submit(function(evt){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    cache: false,
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>options/history",
    success: function (data) {
      alert('Data Loaded');
    }
  });
  evt.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

You can use [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to bind to the JavaScript's `submit` event instead. By returning `false` at the end of this handler you can stop the form submission as shown above; or, by using `evt.preventDefault()`.

The `data` property in [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) specifies the data to be sent to the server. As for getting this data you can use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), it will encode the form elements ready for submit them.